# Unable to select a time range in the Energy timeline in Android Studio profiler

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android 2022.3.1 and following the energy profiler docs here https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/energy-profiler#inspect_system_events_wake_locks_jobs_and_alarms

The docs show that I should be able to select a time range by clicking and dragging on the timeline but that does not work for me. I can see the live energy usage timeline but it is not clickable or interactive at all.

I am able to repro this on a brand new project with an empty activity

[image]